# VBA: Variable not defined

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the IIF function in the code below but it gives me a Compile error that states that "Variable [is] not defined". It highlights the "Zero" in fifth line of code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub macro()

Dim ws As Worksheet
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    MsgBox IIf(ws.Range("A1") = 0, “Zero”, “Nonzero”)
End With

End Sub
```

I don't know why it's pulling this error as I thought that the range of a cell does not have to be defined. I also tried defining the Range as a variable but that did not resolve it either.

What would be the problem here?

Comment: You never assigned `ws`

Comment: The `With` block has no effect here. Remove the `ws` declaration, and replace `ws.Range` with `.Range`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because you're missing to set `ws`

so either it has to be `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` itself and so go like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub macro()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    MsgBox IIf(.Range("A1") = 0, "Zero", "Nonzero") '<~~ '.Range("A1")' implies that the object following the 'With' keyword is assumed to be just before the dot 
End With
```

or it has to be a different sheet, and then go like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub macro()

Dim ws As Worksheet
set ws =ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") '<~~ set the "new" worksheet
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    MsgBox IIf(ws.Range("A1") = 0, "Zero", "Nonzero")
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks. But I just don't understand why defining `ws` and then using `ws.Range` did not do the trick. Is it because I used the `with` statement where I refer to the worksheet?

Comment: Please ignore the above comment.  I reread your answer and I understand. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: with `Dim ws As Worksheet` you only _declared_ a variable named `ws` being of type `Worksheet`. but you didn't initialize it, so VBA doesn't know what actual object `ws` should reference. if you add `set ws =ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")` statement, then the `ws` variable is initialized to reference a real object (i.e. the `Worksheet` named "Sheet2" in the `Workbook` where the macro resides in)

Comment: I've edited my code but despite the change there is still the same Compile error where it states that the variable is not defined. The error highlights the 'Zero', which is the second parameter in the `IIF` function. I don't have to define "Zero", would I?

Comment: look for double quotes: “ vs ".  this a deadly annoying issue. see edited answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't even realize that!

Comment: you are welcome. if my answer fulfilled your question please mark it as accepted. thank you